# Stripe NoMethodError: undefined method `charges' for nil:NilClass in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, webhooks

I'm trying to have my app record successful charges from Stripe via Webhook.  This is based on Chris Oliver's GoRails discussion on Stripe Webhooks.  I'm using the Koudoku gem to establish the Stripe functionality.  I'm running into an error when I try to load the JSON object into the Charges tables.

Here's the error that occurs when I try to record an event:

```
RecordCharges.new.call(event)
Subscription Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."stripe_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["stripe_id", "cus_withheldforexample"]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `charges' for nil:NilClass
```

In my app, Users have one Subscriptions.  Subscriptions have many Charges.  Charges belong to Subscriptions.

Here's the schema:

```
create_table "charges", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "stripe_id"
t.string   "amount"
t.string   "card_last4"
t.string   "card_type"
t.string   "card_exp_month"
t.string   "card_exp_year"
t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
t.integer  "subscription_id"
end

create_table "subscriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "stripe_id"
t.integer  "plan_id"
t.string   "last_four"
t.integer  "coupon_id"
t.string   "card_type"
t.float    "current_price"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
end
```

My Stripe.rb file

```
class RecordCharges
def call(event)
    charge = event.data.object 
    subscription = Subscription.find_by(stripe_id: charge.customer)

    subscription.charges.create(
        stripe_id: charge.id,
        amount: charge.amount,
        card_last4: charge.source.last4,
        card_type: charge.source.brand,
        card_exp_month: charge.source.exp_month,
        card_exp_year: charge.source.exp_year 
        )
end
end

StripeEvent.configure do |events|
events.subscribe 'charge.succeeded', RecordCharges.new
end
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: `subscription` returns nil.  So I'd probably make it `find_by!` and raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error then rescue it.  Does the charge have a customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Subscription.find_by(stripe_id: charge.customer)` is coming back nil. Either your `charge` doesn't have a `customer` and/or you don't have a `Subscription` by that `stripe_id`.

If you do a `find_by!` your app will raise an appropriate error and if your app is set up correctly it will 404 in production.

Comment: I was using a Stripe event that corresponded to a subscription that no longer existed.  I had reset the database since I last created the user I was attempting this with.  After creating a new user with a new subscription, the event was successfully saved into the database.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help!